# Showing portion of WordPress content after a specific keyword in loop

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm new to SQL and $wpdb so please bear with me.

I'm working on an old WordPress blog with posts dating back to 2002.  It was migrated from another CMS to WordPress a few years ago.

Throughout the past decade, the post headline, date, author info, and sometimes other data (such as issue number) were manually added to the top of each post.  This info is now dynamically populated on newer posts, but still exists within the content on older posts.

What I'm trying to do is add tagging to the site.  Most of the posts are tagged, but tagging functionality was never pushed live.

The tags work fine, but on each tag archive page, I'd like to display the first few paragraphs of *actual* content.  In other words, I'd like it to exclude the first X paragraphs of manually-entered metadata.

That manual post info doesn't always follow a predictable pattern, but it seems to always contain the date on the last line of the post info.

So, within the post's actual content, it could look like this:

```
<h1>[Post Title]</h1>
<p>By [Author], [Title]<br />
[Month] [Day], [Year]</p>

[ACTUAL POST CONTENT]
```

Or it could look like this:

```
<p class="post_title">[Post Title]</p>
<br><br>
By [Author], [Title]<br>
[Month] [Day], [Year]; Issue #[issue]

[ACTUAL POST CONTENT]
```

So the actual number of lines before the post begins is variable, but the presence of the date on the last line is constant.

What I'm wondering is if there's any way to run a query (within the loop) that searches post_content for a "year" (2002-2012) and displays **only** the three paragraphs after the line containing the year.

Thanks for your help.  I hope my run-on sentences weren't too, um, run-on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (paste it in your functions.php file in your template folder), as you said the first three paragraphs after a 4 digit year between 2002 and 2012, so it'll filter the content and will find the year(2002, 2003... 2012) and will return the first three paragraphs (text wrapped in `<p>` tags)

```
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_year');
function filter_year($content)
{
    $text=$content;
    preg_match('/(20)(\d{2})/', $text, $matches);
    if($matches && ($matches[0] >= 2002 && $matches[0] <= 2012))
    {
        $matches_splited=preg_split('/20[0-9]{2}/', $text);
        preg_match_all('/<p.*?\>(.*?)<\/p>/si', $matches_splited[1], $paras);
        if($paras)
        {
            $c=0;
            foreach($paras[0] as $p)
            {
                if($c <= 2) $new_content.=$p;
                $c++;
            }
            return $new_content;
        }   
    }
    return $content;
}
```

From following content

Beginning Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing 
`2010` `<p>First Paragraph</p><p>Second Paragraph</p><p>Third Paragraph</p><p>Fourth Paragraph</p><p>Fifth Paragraph</p>`

You will get

```
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
```

And this'll echo

```
First Paragraph
Second Paragraph
Third Paragraph
```